# Mac Mail sometimes sending messages as attachment rather than as body

Tags: mail.app, ms-office

Our company has a remote worker who uses Mac Mail. Most of the time, and that's the difficult part - it doesn't appear to be every time, when this person forwards email with attachments, the body of the email is encoded as an attachment. Its very hard to read and confusing for the recipient of the email. The recipients having difficulty are pc based users using various versions of MS Outlook.
Web based browsers don't seem to have the same problem, just the Outlook users.
Is there a setting on the Mac side that would cause this?
We've been fighting this for a few months and haven't found any solutions yet.
Thanks

Comment: Are those replies, are those send with attachment in the mail or using share menu

Comment: So your Mac user is using mail.app to connect to your MS Exchange server? I want to make sure because at a place I used to work at we had *nothing but weird problems* with Macs using the built-in mail.app (macOS and iOS). We never did find a solution except to use the (free) Mac/iOS version of Outlook. So, yeah, MS Exchange and Apple-native mail/calendar apps do not work and play well together and we never found out why.

Comment: We don't have an Exchange server, but it does seem to only be a problem when sending to MS Outlook. I'll have them try using the free version of Outlook for Mac's. Thanks for the suggestion.